# delete existing row from data table

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to delete a row from datatable according to the selected value from the grid view

I tried to make it, but I failed

```
protected void GV_Repair_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    var row = GV_Repair.Rows[e.RowIndex];                            
    newdt.Rows.Remove();       
    bind_grid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a **static data source**, you can do this:

```cs
protected void GV_Repair_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{    
    newdt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);      
    bind_grid();
}
```

If the **datasource is dynamic**, you will need a hidden field (if you don't have one already) in GridView's template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
        <!-- Other Items -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And change the row deleting method:

```
protected void GV_Repair_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{    
    int id = 0;
    GridViewRow row = GV_Repair.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    HiddenField hdnId = row.FindControls("hdnId") as HiddenField;

    if(hdnId != null && int.TryParse(hdnId.Value, out id)
    {
        //Logic to delete from table where Id = id

    }

    bind_grid();
}
```

Comment: My Data source is dynamic :(